# How to load data from excel into combobox when i debug the application

Tags: c#, excel

im trying to import data from excel into combobox

I want it to be load when i debug the application , so when the application is opened, the combobox already filled with the data from the excel

```
public void fill_comboBox()
        {
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Acct.No.xlsx"); //example path
                xlWS = xlWb.Sheets[1];
                xlRange = xlWS.UsedRange;

                row = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                col = xlRange.Columns.Count;


                fulldata = new string[row][];


                for (int i = 0; i < fulldata.Length; i++)
                {
                    fulldata[i] = new string[col];

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                    {
                        fulldata[i][j] = xlWS.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].value2.ToString();
                        //MessageBox.Show(fulldata[i][j]);
                    }
                }

                closeExcel(xlApp);


                for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(fulldata[i][0]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

and i put the function in

```
       public Form1()
        {
            fill_comboBox();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

i dont know where is the mistake , because it doesnt work after i debug the application

expected result = all data from the excel is in the combobox after i debug the app without press any button

actual result = no data in combobox

Thankyou for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put method calls that involve controls before InitializeComponent - InitializeComponent sets up the form controls, and typically needs to happen first

I'd recommend you put your call to fill_Combobox in a Form_Load event handler instead. Show the form designer, click on any blank part of the background of the form to select the form, click the lightning bolt in the properties grid to switch to the events list for the form, double click the empty cell next to Load. The editor switches to code view inside a newly created method called Form_Load or similar. Put your call in there instead

Comment: AHHH ,Yes i try to put the method to form_load now and it works, thankyou it really helps

Comment: I suspect that initializecomponent was replacing your carefully filled combobox with a new one, or blanking the items of the existing one. Either way; object lesson for today "do initializecomponent first" :)

Answer (score 0):

Use UI control object after component ready (InitializeComponent)

So you should change to below:

```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       fill_comboBox(); // do after components initialized 
   }
```

By the way, C# combobox can specify DisplayField and ValueField, it will easy to understand

Set field by:

```
   ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Text";
   ComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
   ComboBox.Items.Add(new { Text = "text", value = "value" });
```